# I need some help on solving a recursive function question

Tags: functions, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I'm working on a recursive function task which i'm a bit stuck at. I've tried to google it on how I can solve this task, but with no luck

Here is the task:

> *Provide a recursive function $r$ on $A$** *which gives the number of
>   characters in the string*

I Hope I can get some help here, since i've tried nearly everything.

Thanks alot for your kind help!

Comment: What are we allowed to do to the string? What does the * notation mean? What about adding 1 somewhere while deleting a character?

Comment: Could you show some of the nearly everything you've tried?

Comment: @snarski, i believe this is the definition of $A$*: assume that A is a amount of characters. The amount of strings of $A$ is the smallest amount of $A$* such that

1. $\Lambda$ element in $A$*

2. if $s$ \in $A$* and $x$ $\in$ $A$, then $\in$ $A$* $sx$, where $sx$ is the result of merging $s$ with $x$

Answer (score 2):

This seems rather a programing question than a mathematical one, but the idea of recursiveness would be something like:

1. if the string is empty, answer 0
2. otherwise, answer is 1 + the lenght of the substring after second position

This recursiveness only make sense in implementations such as **C**'s $0$-terminated strings.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly see if this helps you.

r = f(A)

f(A) = 0 if f(A) =  ∅

```
 = 1 + f(A-{c}) otherwise
```

where {c} is the character extracted from the string.

Comment: thanks for your answer @mihirj. Does phi stand for 3,14 or i'm I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: no.. i mean a null set (null string in your case). I don't know how to insert that symbol.

Comment: @mihirj This is the "\emptyset" character in latex, $\emptyset$.